# How to get a list of most recently opened files OS wide

Tags: python, macos, file, unix, recent-file-list

How to get a list of most recently opened/written files on the OS?

Mac OS used to have "recent files" in the menu (though it loaded incredibly slowly).

I guess maybe it would be possible to use `locate` somehow.

Looking for a fast way either in Python or bash.

Comment: You may have to use ps, pstree, lsof, find, top commands to do something like that. For ex: for pid in `pstree -hapncG|cut -d',' -f2|cut -d' ' -f1`; do /usr/sbin/lsof -p $pid 2>/dev/null; done | sort | uniq -c > somefile.txt  .... OR lsof|grep "\/.*\/"